# error API Type 'Query' is not assignable to type '[any[], any]' const [results]: [any[], any] = await conn.query(sql, [imageId, sevenDaysAgo]);

Tags: node.js

This is my code. Then I've got an error while I am running.

Then I got a following error.

error  TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);

```
 router.get("/votes/statistics/:imageId", async (req, res) => {
    const imageId = parseInt(req.params.imageId); // Extract imageId from URL
  
    // Calculate the date 7 days ago from the current date
    const sevenDaysAgo = new Date();
    sevenDaysAgo.setDate(sevenDaysAgo.getDate() - 7);
  
    // SQL query to retrieve vote statistics
    const sql = `
      SELECT 
        DATE(votedate) AS voteDate, 
        COUNT(*) AS voteCount
      FROM Votes
      WHERE imageId = ?
      AND votedate >= ?
      GROUP BY DATE(votedate)
      ORDER BY voteDate`;
  
    try {
      // Retrieve data from the database
      const [results]: [any[], any] = await conn.query(sql, [imageId, sevenDaysAgo]);

      // Ensure that results is an array before iterating over it
      if (!Array.isArray(results)) {
        throw new Error("Query results are not iterable");
      }

      // Iterate over the results and construct the vote statistics array
      const voteStatistics = results.map(row => ({
        voteDate: row.voteDate,
        voteCount: row.voteCount,
      }));

      res.json({ success: true, imageId, voteStatistics });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "An error occurred while fetching data" });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is in this line.

```
const [results]: [any[], any] = await conn.query(sql, [imageId, sevenDaysAgo]);
```

The return type of `conn.query` is an array that first element is the rows by the query, and second element is an object and an array that contains result set and metadata.

so you need to fix your code as following.

```
const [results, fields] = await conn.query(sql, [imageId, sevenDaysAgo]);
```

Best regards.